# How to call method with &mut self from inside another method of the same type?

Tags: rust

I've got a `Scanner` struct that has a `scan(&mut self)` method implemented. It looks like this.

```
pub struct Scanner {
    input: String,
    output: Vec<String>,
    state: ScannerState,
}

impl Scanner {
    pub fn scan(&mut self) {
        self.state = ScannerState::CharMode;
        for character in self.input.chars() {
            match character {
                i @ '0'...'9'   => self.output.push(format!("Integer digit: {}", i)),
                '+'             => self.output.push("Addition operator: +".to_string()),
                '-'             => self.output.push("Subtraction operator: -".to_string()),
                '*'             => self.output.push("Multiplication operator: *".to_string()),
                '/'             => self.output.push("Division operator: /".to_string()),
                '%'             => self.output.push("Modulus operator: %".to_string()),
                '^'             => self.output.push("Exponent operator: ^".to_string()),
                '='             => self.output.push("Assignment operator: =".to_string()),
                ';'             => self.output.push("Statement terminator: ;".to_string()),
                c @ 'a'...'z'| c @ 'A'...'Z'
                                => self.output.push(format!("Variable name: {}", c)),
                ' '             => self.output.push("Space, ignoring.".to_string()),
                z @ _           => self.output.push(format!("Unrecognized token: {}", z))
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

However, as you might suspect, the state of the `Scanner` will change, and it will need to treat tokens differently in different states. Therefore, it would be useful to call a private method on the `Scanner` from within the `scan()` method itself, akin to this:

```
pub fn scan(&mut self) {
    self.state = ScannerState::CharMode;

    while self.state == ScannerState::CharMode {
        for character in self.input.chars() {
            self.char_match(character);
        }
        self.state = ScannerState::Done;
    }
}

fn char_match(&mut self, c: char) {
    match c {
        '+'             => self.output.push("Addition operator: +".to_string()),
        '-'             => self.output.push("Subtraction operator: -".to_string()),
        '*'             => self.output.push("Multiplication operator: *".to_string()),
        '/'             => self.output.push("Division operator: /".to_string()),
        '%'             => self.output.push("Modulus operator: %".to_string()),
        '^'             => self.output.push("Exponent operator: ^".to_string()),
        '='             => self.output.push("Assignment operator: =".to_string()),
        ';'             => self.output.push("Statement terminator: ;".to_string()),
        ' '             => self.output.push("Space, ignoring.".to_string()),
        'q'             => self.state = ScannerState::QuitMode,
        i @ '0'...'9'   => self.output.push(format!("Integer digit: {}", i)),
        c @ 'a'...'z'   => self.output.push(format!("Variable name: {}", c)),
        z @ _           => self.output.push(format!("Unrecognized token: {}", z))
    }
}
```

But wait! We can't do that, Rust tells us:

```
src/scanner.rs:34:17: 34:21 error: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.input` is also borrowed as immutable
src/scanner.rs:34                 self.char_match(character);
                                  ^~~~
```

Yet our `char_match()` method NEEDS to have a mutable reference to `self`, since it pushes, and `push()`ing on a `Vec` requires mutability. My question then, is given the preceding knowledge, **what is the ideal way to remedy this situation?**

Will I simply have to write `scan()` as a long method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make `char_match` stateless:

```
pub fn scan(&mut self) {
    self.state = ScannerState::CharMode;

    while self.state == ScannerState::CharMode {
        for character in self.input.chars() {
            match char_match(character) {
                Some(string) => self.output.push(string),
                None => self.state = ScannerState::QuitMode
            }
        }
        self.state = ScannerState::Done;
    }
}

fn char_match(c: char) -> Option<String> {
    Some(match c {
        '+' => "Addition operator: +".into(),
        '-' => "Subtraction operator: -".into(),
        '*' => "Multiplication operator: *".into(),
        '/' => "Division operator: /".into(),
        '%' => "Modulus operator: %".into(),
        '^' => "Exponent operator: ^".into(),
        '=' => "Assignment operator: =".into(),
        ';' => "Statement terminator: ;".into(),
        ' ' => "Space, ignoring.".into(),

        'q' => return None,

        i @ '0'...'9' => format!("Integer digit: {}", i),
        c @ 'a'...'z' => format!("Variable name: {}", c),
        z @ _         => format!("Unrecognized token: {}", z)
    })
}
```

This avoids borrowing altogether, and is also more composable.

Comment: (To future readers) To avoid all the allocation and copies of the static strings before `'q'`, then instead consider using and returning `Option<std::borrow::Cow>`.

Answer (score 4):

`char_match` does not need mutable access to `self`. Mutable access to `self.output` and `self.state` will be enough. If you don't give it access to `self.input` the compiler will no longer complain.